# How can a html IMG tag breaks this php mail function?

Tags: php, html, email

I use this form code for years without problem. The entire code works, every tag is ok, but if I put any  tag on it it just shows me a failure message. The tag can be empty and will still stop the mail function (on php).

- Headers looks fine.
- I tried to use \" for quotes on image tag
- And I tried to put the tag on vars too.

It took me a while until I figured out which tag was messing, I am 100% sure that is the img tag (when I just remove it the code works), the question is.. why?

Here is my code:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['BTEnvia'])){

$email_remetente = "youremail@youremail.com"; // SENDER (MUST BE A EMAIL FROM THE SAME DOMAIN AS YOUR SERVER)
$email_destinatario = "youremail@youremail.com"; // RECEIVER (ANY EMAIL CAN RECEIVE IT)
$email_reply = "$email";
$email_assunto = "!!! SUBJECT !!!";

$nome = $_POST['nomea'];


// IMAGE BELOW ON THE SECOND LINE

$email_conteudo = "<html><head></head><body><table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' width='100%' border='1'>";
$email_conteudo .= "<tr height='50' align='center'><td><img src='http://fullpathofimagehere.jpg'></td><td><h1 style='text-align:center;'>ABERTURA DE CRÉDITO</h1> </td></tr>"; //IMG TAG IS ON THIS LINE
$email_conteudo .= "<tr height='50' align='center' width='100%' border='1'><td>Nome</td><td> $nome </td></tr>"; 
$email_conteudo .= "</table></body></html>"; 


// HEADERS
    $email_headers = implode ( "\n",array ( "From: $email_remetente", "Reply-To: $email_reply", "Subject: $email_assunto","Return-Path:  $email_remetente","MIME-Version: 1.0","X-Priority: 3","Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" ) );


if (mail ($email_destinatario, $email_assunto, $email_conteudo, $email_headers)){
    echo "Success"; 
}
else{
    echo "<b>Fail!</b>";
}


}   
?>
```

And here is the html code if you want to test it for yourself, just put everything on the same file and save as a .php

```
 <form action="<? $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="POST">


<input type="text" placeholder="Nome da Empresa" id="nomea" name="nomea" />



     <input type="submit" name="BTEnvia" value="Enviar"  />

</form>
```

Comment: use chunk_split or break the body string manually. see RFC 2045

Comment: Did not work, same error.

Comment: maybe due to the unicode multibyte letters. look for the unicode implementation of the chunk_split, or use base64 body encoding with proper header. google "php mail base64 html".

Answer (score 0):

Either try putting a `/>` at the end:

```
<img src='http://fullpathofimagehere.jpg' />
```

or I think the `//` inside the URL might be causing a problem but I'm not too sure about that.

EDIT:

How about trying to make a div and set the div's background url to whatever image you want? (you will have to do some inline styling inside the php)

Comment: Sorry, its not that. 

Even when I leave the src='' empty it still fails. 

And I closed the tag on my first try (/>). I even tried some prehistorique html like <img>path</img>. Everything stops the mail function.